# How To Calculate Percentage in Power BI Using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created two measures in Power BI called **Count of Appointment Status for Kept** and **Count of Appointment Status for DNS**. These measures are counting and filtering values in **Client'[Appointment Status]**. I'm not sure if the **CALCULATE** and **COUNTA** functions are the best way to accomplish this task.

```
Count of Appointment Status for Kept = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Client'[Appointment Status]),
    'Client'[Appointment Status] IN { "Kept" }
)


Count of Appointment Status for DNS = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Client'[Appointment Status]),
    'Client'[Appointment Status] IN { "DNS" }
)

Percentage of Total No Show = 
FORMAT(
     CALCULATE(Client[Count of Appointment Status for Kept])
     /Client[Count of Appointment Status for DNS])
     , "0.00%)
```

Nevertheless, I'm trying to create a measure to calculate the percent of **"No Show"**. When I do it, the decimal places gives me an issue. For example, 8.50 turns into 850.0%. I'm sure there is a syntax issue, I just don't know where.

Comment: Is `Kept` always less than `DNS` in terms of counting?

Comment: No, Kept is usually more.

Comment: So why is `850.0%` incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct solution:

```
Percentage of Total No Show =
FORMAT (
    (
        CALCULATE (
            Client[Count of Appointment Status for Kept]
        ) / Client[Count of Appointment Status for DNS]
    ) / 100,
    "0.00%"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in the past - power bi tends to multiply by 100 when using % 
the way I get around it is by just dividing by 100
eg

Percentage of Total No Show = 
FORMAT(
     CALCULATE(Client[Count of Appointment Status for Kept])
     /(Client[Count of Appointment Status for DNS]) * 100)
     , "0.00%)

Answer (score 0):

First we have to create column by using below formula `(each individual value) / (sum of all values)` and type is number

[image]

after that select the column and mention format is percentage symbol

[image]